# Cuda scan - different results in Debug and Release modes when using shared memory

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to write segmented scan in cuda where segment's length equals warp's length (32). Here's my kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(int totalSize, unsigned short* result)
{
    __shared__ unsigned short s_data[1024];

    const unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int intraWarpThreadId = threadIdx.x & 31;

    if (tid >= totalSize)
        return;

    s_data[threadIdx.x] = result[tid];
    __syncthreads();

    IntraWarpScan(s_data, threadIdx.x, intraWarpThreadId);
    __syncthreads();

    result[tid] = s_data[threadIdx.x];
}

__device__ void IntraWarpScan(unsigned short* s_data, unsigned int intraBlockThreadId, unsigned int& intraWarpThreadId)
{
    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 1)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 1];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 2)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 2];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 4)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 4];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 8)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 8];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 16)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 16];
}
```

I suppose I'm having some race conditions in shared memory but I cannot figure out why they happen. Since each segment is scanned within a warp I don't need any synchronisation inside IntraWarpScan procedure, right? But without synchronising after each if instruction in IntraWarpScan I'm getting wrong results in Release build. In Debug I'm getting correct results.

On the other hand I'm getting correct results in both builds if I decide not to use shared memory but just the device memory, like so:

```
__global__ void kernel(int totalSize, unsigned short* result)
{
    const unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int intraWarpThreadId = threadIdx.x & 31;

    if (tid >= totalSize)
        return;

    IntraWarpScan(result, tid, intraWarpThreadId);
    __syncthreads();
}

__device__ void IntraWarpScan(unsigned short* s_data, unsigned int intraBlockThreadId, unsigned int& intraWarpThreadId)
{
    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 1)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 1];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 2)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 2];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 4)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 4];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 8)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 8];

    if (intraWarpThreadId >= 16)
        s_data[intraBlockThreadId] += s_data[intraBlockThreadId - 16];
}
```

But it's obviously slower so I'd prefer to understand what happens in my first kernel that causes wrong results in release build. I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Try declaring the `__shared__` memory as `volatile`. It might be compilation optimization (and this effect is described in the programming guide)

Comment: thanks, eh now I feel silly. Indeed, adding volatile solved the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a short answer for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks talonmies for pointing out the problem.
The solution is to add volatile in shared memory declaration. Basically in Release mode compiler is allowed to hold values in registers and not honor intermediate stores to shared memory. In the case when threads access shared memory locations modified by other threads, the memory should be declared as volatile to turn off such optimizations.

Very good and in depth explanation can be found here: [When to use volatile with shared CUDA Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331009/when-to-use-volatile-with-shared-cuda-memory)