# Opencl kernel local memory

Tags: opencl

OpenCL provides local memory similar to shared memory in cuda. In cuda we have to use volatile with shared memory , because If you don't declare a shared array as volatile, then the compiler is free to optimize locations in shared memory by locating them in registers. But it will be problem if threads communicate between each other. My question is do we have to follow same approach(of using volatile) in opencl kernel also and if yes how should I do it?

Comment: I think this is a miss use of volatile. what you need here is memory barrieres, not volatile

Answer (score 3):

1) you don't need to use `volatile` with CUDA shared memory. [Here is a good answer explaining that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331009/when-to-use-volatile-with-shared-cuda-memory) Quote:

> __syncthreads() call is sufficient to force thread synchronization as well as to force any register-cached values in shared memory to be evicted back to shared memory.

2) the OpenCL equivalent of `__syncthreads()` is `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)`. There is also a weaker `mem_fence` which is (supposedly) comparable to CUDA's `__threadfence` or `__threadfence_block`.

Comment: it's worth to mention that in situations when all you need is a memory consistency, but threads do not need to stop all together at 1 common point, then declaring a shared buffer as `volatile` usually provides better performance then using `barrier(...)` .